# Stop wmplayer.exe from running in the background on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, windows-media-player, windows-media-center, media-player

wmplayer.exe is always running on my Vista Laptop (Dell XPS M1530).I tried killing it but it comes back again and eats up a lot of memory.I checked windows services and did not find any windows media player service running.Here is the configuration of the Media Player services on my laptop.

```
**Name                                     Status        Startup Type**
Windows Media Center Extender Service                    Disabled
Windows Media Center Receiver Service                    Manual
Windows Media Center Scheduler Service                  Manual
Windows Media Center Service Launcher                    Automatic (Delayed Start)
Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service              Disabled
```

I also tried doing http://arcterex.net/blog/archives/2008/05/15/how_i_fixed_my_wmplayerexe_alw.html but did not find any devices listed in Mobil Sync Center.

Comment: Have you tried to plug in a device and get it listed there? Afterwards the linked trick maybe works. And I would check, if this wmplayer.exe is a virus in disguise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell Premium Remote Control Service ( WMPCONTROLLERSERVICE.EXE ) was causing this.Once I uninstalled this, the problem went away.